# Django attaching multiple events to a model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider I have a model called '*Pub*'. What I want is: instances of *Pub* will have multiple events i.e. *Pub A* will have three events (events like say rock concert on 23rd June etc. name and date are important), *Pub B* will have 2 events and so on.

Later on frontend I want to retrieve all available pubs on a specific date (i.e. pubs which do not have any event on a specific date).

How do I code this in my backend? I though of creating a separate *Event* model taht has event_name and date as parameters. This *Event* I could use as a foreign key in my *Pub* model.

Will it be a correct approach? Or any other efficient way of doing this keeping in mind what I want to achieve on my frontend? Also, what data types will I use to store such events?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way of creating a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Actually, it's backwards.  The Event model should have a foreign key to the Pub model.

Comment: I wonder it is ManytoManyField? Like Pub has many events? So that I can add multiple events while creating a Pub instance?

Comment: No, because that would mean an Event could also be in multiple Pubs. As thebjorn says, the ForeignKey should live on Event and point to Pub, so that a Pub can have multiple Events and you can add the events into an inline form when creating the Pub.

Comment: @Nitish it seems unfeasible for an event (at a specific time) to be at two different Pubs, i.e. a m2m field is not appropriate.  When a Pub has many Event, then Event should have a ForeignKey to Pub. You will then access all Events at a Pub with `mypub.event_set.filter(...)`.

Comment: In that case I will have to create events beforehand right? I can not edit say Pub in my admin interface to add more events?

Comment: No you *will* be able to add events inline in the Pub editing screen.

Comment: Okay great, I will try that now :) Thanks!

Comment: No (Events can be created before or after Pub, depending on whether the foreign key to Pub is nullable or not), and yes (you will be able to add Events from the Pub admin, look at InlineModelAdmin, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects, for details).

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot!